# Axis label in Flot

Tags: javascript, flot

Does anyone know how one can set the label or title of an axis in Flot?

I've read the API but it doesn't seem to have that feature...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are none built-in to flot.

Your best bet is to do it yourself via positioned divs, but if you are adventurous, you can look at the [issue](https://github.com/flot/flot/issues/121) (Or the original [issue](http://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=42)) and see how other people have dealt with it.

Specifically, there are two people who have recently made label-related revisions to flot:

https://github.com/RuiPereira/flot/raw/axislabels/jquery.flot.axislabels.js

http://github.com/xuanluo/flot-axislabels

Comment: I'm going to try doing myself with positioned divs.  Thank you.

Comment: The y axis label on the [homepage](http://www.flotcharts.org/) is done just as this answer says: by carefully positioned divs.  It appears however that [version 0.9 of Flot will include axis labels](https://github.com/flot/flot/pull/1090).

Comment: Thanks @MatthewWalker - once 0.9 is released, I will update my answer

Comment: welp. ... it worked, but it also removed my custom label formatting, so no go

Answer (score 37):

Shameless self-plug: I fixed and greatly extended xuanluo's flot-axislabels plugin: http://github.com/markrcote/flot-axislabels/ As far as I know, it is the best solution for axis labels at the moment.

Comment: this worked for me woo hoo.  methinks this can be the accepted answer

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. Integration was painless

Comment: This is absolutely the right answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 36):

i'm using this workaround:

```
yaxis: {
tickFormatter: function(val, axis) { return val < axis.max ? val.toFixed(2) : "CZK/l";}
}
```

Very simple, the max value on the Y axis is replaced by a custom string. I've not tested on the X axis, but I see no reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: sadly it doesn't show on mine as Flot decided to hide the last (max) tick mark from graph

Comment: what's the purpose of toFixed(2)?

Comment: @knocte Without the toFixed(2), you might end up seeing this sort of thing on your graph: `11.5000000004`. Not very attractive.

Answer (score 6):

A suggestion I saw that works pretty well is to put the graph in the middle of a 3x3 table. Then the labels can be put in the others cells.

```
<table style="text-align:center">
  <tr>
    <td></td>

    <td>Plot Title Goes Here</td>

    <td> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Y Axis Label</td>

    <td>
      <div id="graph here" style="width:600px;height:300px"></div>
    </td>

    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>

    <td>X Axis Label Goes Here</td>

    <td></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: A decent workaround. I think for the y axis, maybe use an image so you can get it vertical.

Answer (score 3):

Example for 2dims graph (x and y axis) solved with pure css.

Y axis:

```
#placeholder:after {
    content: 'Speed';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: -50px;
    font-weight: 600;
    /* Safari */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* IE */
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Opera */
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Internet Explorer */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

X axis:

```
#placeholder:before {
    content: 'Time';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30px;
    left: 50%;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("<div class='axisLabel yaxisLabel'></div>")
        .text("Pressure")
        .appendTo($("#yl_1"));
```

This will works too.

Answer (score 0):

I use szpapas idea.

I added more jquery code below it to overwrite x-axis like this.

```
            $('div.flot-x-axis div.flot-tick-label.tickLabel:nth-child(1)').html("Berhad")
            $('div.flot-x-axis div.flot-tick-label.tickLabel:nth-child(2)').html("")
            $('div.flot-x-axis div.flot-tick-label.tickLabel:nth-child(3)').html("Sdn Bhd")
            $('div.flot-x-axis div.flot-tick-label.tickLabel:nth-child(4)').html("")
            $('div.flot-x-axis div.flot-tick-label.tickLabel:nth-child(5)').html("Enterprise")
            $('div.flot-x-axis div.flot-tick-label.tickLabel:nth-child(6)').html("")
            $('div.flot-x-axis div.flot-tick-label.tickLabel:nth-child(7)').html("Koperasi")
```